# Guava Cache overriding error

Tags: java, generics, guava

Noob question on generics.
I was trying to override the `loadAll` method in the `CacheLoader` class.
Its signature is

```
public Map<K,V> loadAll(Iterable<? extends K> keys)
```

now when I override with `loadAll(List<Integer>)` it throws an error and suggests removing the `@Override` annotation however the same works with `loadAll(Iterable<? extends Integer>)`. Can someone tell me the difference. Isn't `list` an iterable too?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have a `Map<Integer>`? The generic `Map` interface contains a `K` key and `V` value type (`Map<K,V>`)

Comment: Sorry! corrected the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) `List` does implement the interface `Iterable`.

Your new signature:

```
public Map<K,V> loadAll(List<Integer>)
```

however does not override the method:

```
public Map<K,V> loadAll(Iterable<? extends K> keys)
```

because you restrict the callers of your method to arguments of type `List` but to "fullfil the promise" of the interface that you are trying to override you'd have to accept arguments of type `Iterable<? extends K> keys`. If you provide the interface with the argument type `Iterable<? extends Integer>` you are doing exactly that.

Another example to clarify this: Your non-working signature wouldn't accept a `Set` whereas the original method of the interface would.